# How to change value of one autocomplete depending on another autocomplete in angular2

Tags: angular, autocomplete

how could i create two auto complete dependes one on another autocomplete.
i have tried my code is given below

```
<div class="col-md-4 xs-p1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>City <em>*</em></label>
                             <input ng2-auto-complete [(ngModel)]="contact.pCity" [source]="citySuggestions.bind(this)"
                                list-formatter="pCity" display-property-name="pCity" placeholder="Search by City"
                                class="form-control1" style="border-radius:0px">
                            <!--<input class="form-control1" id="height2" placeholder="Enter City" type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.pCity">-->
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 xs-p1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>State <em>*</em></label>
                            <input ng2-auto-complete  [(ngModel)]="contact.pState" [source]="codeSuggestions.bind(this)"
                                list-formatter="pState" display-property-name="pState" placeholder="Search by State"
                               class="form-control1" style="border-radius:0px" (valueChanged)="getCitySuggestions($event)" max-num-list="5">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

this didnt work please help. is there link avable for this

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide getCitySuggestions function?
.bind(this) is unnecessary